# When child says "Mama", should I say "Say", "Speak", or "Tell"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Till now I used to say "Tell", but after reading [this article](https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/tellsay.html) I am not very sure about "Tell" since there are other possibilities too.

When child says "Mama", should I say "Say", "Speak", or "Tell"?

Comment: I don't think your question has to do with the linked article because to say just "tell" sounds as much awkward as to use other verbs, especially to a child. Is the word **tell** used in your native language?

Comment: "Yes, my love?"

Comment: It depends on the context, and it is not clear which context you mean.  If you want your child to tell you something, then you would say "Tell Mama what you want."  If you want the child to speak the word "Mama", then you would say "Say 'Mama'!"

Comment: Are you a Spanish speaker?

Comment: @Araucaria I am a Hindi speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what your baby/toddler is thinking, you might say

> **Tell** Mama, sweetie

If you want to know what an adult is thinking, you might say

> Please **say** what you think

If you want to know what an adolescent is thinking, just look at them and say

> **Speak!**

They are all ways of telling the listener you want them to **vocalise** what they are thinking.

Answer (score 3):

In English we don't normally use a verb like *speak, say* or *tell* in this situation. We normally say:

- What is it?

or, for example, if the child's name is Maria:

- Yes, Maria?

or just:

- Yes?